# Anomaly detection across groups

Tags: multilevel-analysis, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for anomaly detection in a particular context. I have data where each observation is a member of a group. I know the groups in the data. Each group has a varying number of observations, some groups with lots of observations and some groups with only a small number of observations.

I am interested in detecting groups that are anomalous, meaning the distribution of observations within a group is unlikely compared to what we see in most groups. The individual data points within a group might not be unusual compared to the whole data set, but when looking at all the data points in a group as a whole, a group may be unusual compared to other groups. There may be more than one type of group that is non-anomalous/frequently observed in the data set in terms of that group's distribution of observations.

What method can I use to 1) identify which groups are anomalous and 2) produce some measure of the likelihood or confidence with which we're identifying a group as anomalous?

--- Edited to add a more concrete example --

Think of a group of entry-level sales people going door-to-door and generating leads/customers who are interested in getting an estimate for services. The door-to-door sales staff collects contact information from customers. So at the customer-level, we have a variety of data to look at. Some fields are required when collecting info from a new customer and some are optional. These customer-level attributes include:

- date the lead was collected
- customers' address
- customer's phone number
- customer's email
- a variety of different yes/no boxes to check
- validation data about these fields, such as whether a phone number is working/disconnected/non-existent and whether someone answered the phone when called
- and more

At the employee level, we also have

- number of leads generated by each employee during a given shift
- start/end time of shift
- tenure at the company
- number of completed shifts

We're interested in detecting employees who are faking their data. Data collected from one individual lead may look okay, but when you look at all of a given employee's data, it may look unusual compared to other employees.

For example, suppose the employee turns in a lead that has a missing, fake, or disconnected phone number. Customers don't have to provide a phone number, and customers sometimes do give out false contact info, so every employee is going have that happen sometimes. But one employee having an usually large number of customers with phone numbers that are missing, fake, or disconnected would be cause for concern.

There isn't necessarily a list set out ahead of time of all of the possible things to look to determine if an employee should be investigated. I would treat this as an unsupervised learning problem where we are looking for employees whose customer data looks significantly different in some way from what we normally see with other employees.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Michelle. This is such a vague description of "anomalous" that it's not likely to be answerable.  Could you be more specific about what aspects or properties of a group's observations might characterize an "anomaly"?